# C# can't open a second form 2+ times in a row

Tags: c#, forms, crash

I have this starting off the class.

```
  public partial class Game : Form
        {
            Results toResults = new Results();
```

this is where it shows the form

```
private void ShowResults()
        {
            toResults.Show();
        }
```

I have this being called off a button click

```
private void resultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   
               ShowResults();
            }
```

If I run my program and i click the button to open the 3rd form it works, but if I close it and try again it breaks with this error message (Cannot access a disposed object.) How could I get around this. I have a total of three forms, I found if i open the game class, then click the button to open the results, then close the results and the game i can bypass it. but making that happen each time would not be what I want. How could i make it so I don't have to close the game class to open results multiple times.

Comment: you created a single reference to the form, but the user can close that form rather than just hide it,

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I made the button hide it instead of closing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you [close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx) the form all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed. 
The easiest way to fix it is to handle the [Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event and hide the form in the handler or to create a form just before open it.

```
    public Game()
    {
        Results toResults = new Results();
        toResults.FormClosing += F_FormClosing;
    }

    private void F_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        toResults.Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void ShowResults()
    {
        toResults.Show();
    }
```

Or

```
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        Results toResults;

        private void ShowResults()
        {
           toResults = new Results();
           toResults.Show();
        }
```